# XML parsing: line 1, character 7, semicolon expected

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

An error occurs when running this XML SQL in C#. What is missing? It works fine in SQL Server management studio but not in the c#.

```
protected DataTable ServiceCodes(string orderColumn = default(string), bool orderAscending = true)
{
    string sql = @" SELECT DISTINCT(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS Data  
                             FROM  
                             (
                                 SELECT CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(Text09, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                                 FROM  Assets
                                 WHERE Category = 'Service'
                             ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a) ORDER BY Data";

    return DatabaseConnection.ExecuteDataTable(sql, 120000);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it works in SSMS? I mean the `Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')` ??

Comment: Check the XML text, I expect there is a `&` that gets taken for the start of an xml character entity (which should end with a semicolon). Replace that with `&amp;`.

Comment: Yes it works like a treat in SSMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's some special character in you `Text09` column. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS Data  
FROM  
(
 SELECT CAST('<M>' + replace((select Text09 + '' for xml path('')), ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
 FROM  Assets
 WHERE Category = 'Service'
) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a) ORDER BY Data
```

see [**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8)